# Roboguice not injecting object and causing null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, sharedpreferences, roboguice

I'm trying to create (inject) a SharedPreferences object which is causing a NullPointerException and I can't seem to figure out why.

The error from AndroidStudio:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.tom.android.common.TomApplication.getLoggedIn(TomApplication.java:110)

How I'm injecting:

```
public class TomApplication extends Application {

    @Inject
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

Line (110) giving the error:

```
Boolean loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PrefsHelper.LOGGED_IN, false);
```

And here is my app/build.gradle file:

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>       compileSdkVersion 10
>       buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     applicationId "com.tom.android"
>     minSdkVersion 10
>     targetSdkVersion 20
> }
>
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         runProguard false
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> dependencies {
>
> ```
> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
>
> compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
>
> compile files('libs/android-sqlite-asset-helper.jar') 
>
> }
> ```

Finally, here is my Module:

```
package com.tom.android.common.module;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule; 
import roboguice.inject.SharedPreferencesName;

public class TomModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
 bind(String.class).annotatedWith(SharedPreferencesName.class).toProvider(PreferencesNameProvider.class);
}

}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: check https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/pull/176

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following in your constructor:

```
RoboGuice.injectMembers(context, this);
```